# Discharging a capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge, capacitance

Suppose I have a charged capacitor, meaning there's a voltage (electric potential difference), say, $2V$, between its two plates. We don't know the electirc potential of the individual plates, right? It might be $2V$ and $0V$ or $5V$ and $3V$.

If I connect one plate of a capacitor ($2V$) to an object with electic potential $0V$, the voltage accross the objects will be $2V$. Will there be any current flow? I know, the circuit isn't closed. But it doesn't mean anything - the voltage across objects will cuase a very short current, because the electric charge will move from one object to the other (touch two differently charged spheres, their charge will distribute evenly across both of them, if I'm not mistaken).

You will probably say the other plate is holding the charge the plate, so it won't go to the ground even though there's a potential difference across the plate and the ground. But that implies that voltage doesn't always mean movement of charges (if that's how it works, fine).

Let's see if I understand capacitors correctly - does connecting both plates of a charged capacitor always discharge the capacitor?

Answer (score 1):

To know the electric potential of the plates you first need to define where and if there is a point with zero potential. This point is arbitrary. Once you defined that, you can calculate the potential of the plates. For instance, if one of the plates of the capacitor is defined to be at zero V, then the other plate will be at 2V. If you define it that way and one plate is at 2V it will discharge a little as you connect it with an object at zero volts. How much, it would depend on the object details, but charge will flow until both potentials are the same (likely not longer 2V).

The other plate will remain charged in your setup, as it cannot get rid of the charge, but the potential will change, it will adjust to the new distribution of charges across space.

And finally yes, if you connect the two plates of a capacitor you are closing a circuit and the charges will flow until the potential in both plates is the same. Because of symmetry (assuming both plates are the same size and shape), the final configuration will be a zero charge on each plate.

Answer (score 1):

> We don't know the electirc potential of the individual plates, right?

**Yes**, we do. Or, that depends on what we want to know. Electric potential is just the potential compared to some other point - some arbitrarily chosen reference point.

- If for example, you chose one of the capacitor plates as the reference, then this plate has an electric potential of $0\;\mathrm{V}$ and the other plat $2\;\mathrm{V}$.
- If you compare with ground as the reference, then one plate might have $3\;\mathrm{V}$ and the other $5\;\mathrm{V}$. This is not known, no, but it isn't important unless we need that connection.

> If I connect one plate of a capacitor ($2\;\mathrm{V}$) to an object with electic potential $0\;\mathrm{V}$, the voltage accross the objects will be $2\;\mathrm{V}$.

Now, be accurate here. It depends on *which plate*, since they don't have the same potential.

If you pick the plate at a potential of $2\;\mathrm{V}$, then yes, the potential difference or voltage across this plate and ground at (if ground is $0\;\mathrm{V}$ compared to the same reference - in other words, if ground *is* the reference) will be $2\;\mathrm{V}-0\;\mathrm{V}=2\;\mathrm{V}$. This is the case no matter if they are connected or not.

> Will there be any current flow? I know, the circuit isn't closed. But it doesn't mean anything - the voltage across objects will cuase a very short current, because the electric charge will move from one object to the other

Correct. **Yes**, there will be a current flowing if there is a potential difference across two connected points **if it is is not restricted or resisted by anything along the way!**. Charge will flow from the place of high to low potential until the potentials are equal (the higher one is lowered and the lower one is raised).

At steady conditions in a circuit there will always be equal potential along points on conductors, if there are no components in between.

*If* there is a component in between them, then the current might be resisted and less will flow. If - as the extreme case - the resistance is very large then it acts like the points are not connected at all and no current will flow, even though there is a potential difference across them.

> You will probably say the other plate is holding the charge the plate, so it won't go to the ground even though there's a potential difference across the plate and the ground.

Not understood. Both plates hold charge (maybe), one just holds more than the other (and thus has higher potential).

The charge will never go to ground unless there is a connection to ground. Potential difference or not. What do you mean with this?

> [...] voltage doesn't always mean movement of charges

**True**. The voltage across the two capacitor plates also doesn't mean any charge moving - they *want* to move (therefore the word "potential") and they will if allowed (if they are suddenly connected).

> does connecting both plates of a charged capacitor always discharge the capacitor?

**Yes**. Because by "charging" the capacitor we mean that there is a voltage across it's plates. Because then, if the plates are connected through a circuit, current will flow.

Charge will **always** want to move towards lower electric potential. That is the whole point in electric circuits. So if the potential difference is destroyed, then no charge will want to flow anymore which means no current.

I hope this makes everything more clear.

Comment: I was always taught that electic potential isn't relative, it's just a quantity. However the voltage is defined as difference in electic potential between two points. Ok. So in short - connecting one plate of a charged capacitor to an object such that there's a voltage across the object and plate will discharge the plate a little. Can it discharge the plate completely?

Comment: @user4205580 Electric potential is not an absolute value anymore than gravitational potential is. Gravitational potential energy is $U=mgh$, where the $h$ is the height *from some reference level*. Electric potential is $U=kq/r$, where $q$ is the charge of *the reference point* and $r$ the *distance from it*. There is no such thing as absolute values of potential. It is always compared to some reference.

Comment: @user4205580 As explained, if you connect a point of lower (or higher) potential with one capacitor plate, charges will flow away from (or towards) the plate. This reduces (or raises) the potential on this plate. Charges will flow until the potentials of the plate and the connected object are equal. We call a capacitor *charged* when there is a potential difference across it's two plates. So if the capacitor is totally or only partly discharges, depends on how much the potential is reduced (or raised) on the plate, which depends on the potential of the connected object.

Comment: Then what is the difference between electic potential and voltage? Voltage is the difference in electic potential, and the electic potential itself is relative as well?

Comment: @user4205580 Correct. The difference is that electric potentials are calculated compared to a common reference, while voltage is a difference between any points, not necessarily the same reference. If the electric potential is calculated in two points relative to the same reference, then the difference between them is a *voltage*. The idea is that voltage *compares* potentials, while potentials themselves just are values.

Comment: To summarize: grounding one plate of a charged capacitor can change the voltage across the plates, yes? If so, why all answers here state otherwise? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33598/will-a-charged-capacitor-discharge-if-one-lead-is-connected-to-ground

Comment: @user4205580 Aha, I see the confusion now. **No, it will not**. My answer above is only talking about how charge moves in general - in the unrestricted case. But with capacitor plates, the negative (or positive) charge on on plate attracts the exact same amount of positive (or negative) charge on the other. And it keeps it there. So connecting one plate to ground will not change the fact, that the charge on one plate holds the same amount fixed on the other plate. I have now edited the answer to make this clear. Please, let me know if this is not understandable.

Comment: You say that the opposite charges on the plates keep each other in place, so even connecting one plate to ground won't change the charge on that plate. However, connecting both plates will discharge both plates. How is connecting one plate to the ground different from connecting it to the other plate? The question is why the charge decides to move from one plate to the other once they become connected? Even though the plates keep the charge on each other, connecting them will remove the charge, but connecting one of them to the ground will not, even if the voltage across the plate and ground

Comment: ... was the same as across both plates.

Comment: @user4205580 Connecting both plates to ground means that they are now connected. Then the charge will have this new path to move via. It is only accumulated at the plate because it very much wants to move to the other plate - giving it another path to the other plate simply means that it will now move this way.

Comment: Last question - connecting a charged plate to the ground will not change the charge of the system plate+ground, but it will change the electric potential of that plate (assuming there was voltage across the plate and ground initially). And if the plate potential changes, the voltage across the plates will change as well. IMO.

Comment: Grounding just one plate obviously won't discharge the capacitor, if we define discharging as removing charge from BOTH plates.

Comment: @user4205580 *"but it will change the electric potential of that plate"* Why? Potential comes from the charge of the plates - that doesn't change. The potential across this new plate+ground system is not uniform but is different.

Comment: I have a charged plate and ground. Let's say the potential of the plate is different from that of the ground (relative to an arbitrary point). If I connect the plate to the ground, as you said, plate+ground will have identical potential, different than the potential of the plate before it was connected to the ground. So the new potential of the plate will be different, and so will be the voltage across the plates. Or I don't get it.

Comment: @user4205580 It will only even out and reach identical potential in all parts if *it is unresisted*. And in this case *it is not*! Charge is being held in place on the plate - therefore, the charge distribution will *not* even out but will remain on the plate. That is the main points of the link to the other question, you posted, and see the update made previously to my answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter if we connect outer sides of the plates, or the inner sides, right? http://imgur.com/lSRITVi If so, let me explain what's counterintuitive for me: looking at the the third case above (connecting inner sides), it's obvious why the capacitor will discharge. However, if we connect outer sides of the plates (middle image), will it discharge the capacitor as well? I'm asking because, as you said, the negative charges attract the positive charges, keeping them in place.

Comment: Suppose plate A has 2V and plate B - 0V relative to ground. Now, connect plate A to ground (ground is 0V too, of course). How is that different from connecting outer side of plate A to the outer side of plate B? In both cases every plate keeps the charge on the opposite plate, however in the first case the potential of plate A won't change, whereas in the second case potentials of both plates will 'try' to match.